# basic angular question : @input cant get data from parent component

Tags: angular

sorry this might be a really silly question, but it has been bother me one day.

I want to export data from parent component

[image]

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoItem } from './todo-item/todo-item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'HelloAngular';

  todoItems =[
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'app No.1',
    done: false
  },{
    id: 2,
    value: 'app No.2',
    done: true
  },{
    id: 3,
    value: 'app No.3',
    done: false
  }];
}
```

using an Interface TodoItem

```
export interface TodoItem {
    id: number;
    value: string;
    done: boolean;
}
```

and receiving data in a child component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoItem } from './todo-item'; 


@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-items',
  templateUrl: './todo-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-items.component.css']
})

export class TodoItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @Input() items: TodoItem; 
}
```

and then I was stuck, I try many ways to write html, but nothing showed up...

```
<app-add-form></app-add-form>  <--! this one works-->

<app-todo-items [items]="todoItems[0]"></app-todo-items> <--! nothing shows up-->
```

Comment: In the app.component.html where you have the child component you just need to actually populate the property you've added with `@Input` so it would be something like `<app-todo-items [items]="todoItems[0]">` or whichever one you're after since it's an array.

Comment: Could you share your app.component.html, as to see how you are passing data...

Comment: <app-add-form></app-add-form>

    <app-todo-items [items]="todoItems[0]"></app-todo-items>

Comment: what is there in todo-items.component.html

Comment: please show todo-items.component.html

Comment: thanks everyone, I know my mistake is that I didnt do biding in todo-items.component.html

Comment: If your problem is solved then kindly accept an answer and mark this question as solved

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass your data to a component by using `Input` directive, you need to render the component by its reference in your `app.component.html`. Your `app.component.html` is correct but the problem is in the use of `Input` directive. You need to provide the name of your variable as an argument to it.

```
@Input("items")
items: TodoItem;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
@Input() items: TodoItem[] = [];
```

Then pass in the array like this:

```
<app-todo-items [items]="todoItems"></app-todo-items>
```

Comment: Your question wasn't clear. You should've specified you were having problems rendering the data, not passing it as you indicated in your question.

Answer (score -1):

My question solved. The mistake is I didnt do binding in the child component template.

like this

{{ items }}

and the code will be complete like this

in child component template:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <label htmlFor="chk_{{item.id}}">
        <input id="chk_{{item.id}}" type="checkbox" [checked]="item.done"> {{ item.value }}
    </label>
    |
    <a href="#">刪除</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

in parent componet template:

```
<app-todo-items [items]="todoItems">
</app-todo-items>
```